# How to determine tables size in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I use Oracle 11 and want to find out the size of my tables (like in megabytes). What should I do? Should I check the file size on server? Or is there any query to run?

Comment: duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3457

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is a query, you can run it in SQL Developer (or SQL*Plus):

```
SELECT DS.TABLESPACE_NAME, SEGMENT_NAME, ROUND(SUM(DS.BYTES) / (1024 * 1024)) AS MB
  FROM DBA_SEGMENTS DS
  WHERE SEGMENT_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES)
 GROUP BY DS.TABLESPACE_NAME,
       SEGMENT_NAME;
```

Comment: Query is useful but doesn't include index. For index size see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/how-to-find-the-actual-space-being-consumed-by-indexes-on-a-table-in-oracle

Comment: DBA/USER SEGMENTS still showing table info even was deleted, Is ther a way to refresh the info or force the new watermark?

Answer (score 74):

If you don't have DBA rights then you can use user_segments table:

```
select bytes/1024/1024 MB from user_segments where segment_name='Table_name'
```

Comment: Thanks, that above query is awesome because usually we don't have DBA access .

Comment: The `user_segments` table is empty in my database.