# How to determine PRECISE size of schema's table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to determine the precise sizes of all tables in schema 'OWNER'.
The thing is, I need to get tables sizes that include also Indexes and LOBs, which apparently aren't stored in dba_segments.

So this simple code actually works, but it's far from giving me the exact size results:

```
 select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024/1024 GB
 from dba_segments
 where segment_type='TABLE' and owner='OWNER'
```

I also tried solutions provided here, but again, it's far from the realistic result : [How to determine tables size in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012559/how-to-determine-tables-size-in-oracle)

How I know  the actual size? I use TOAD and when I click table's Stats/Size, I see the number shown there is far from above select.

Why I need that ? Because I want to get all table names and their size that exceed 500GB.

Comment: You can join `dba_lobs`  to `dba_segments`

Comment: Did you **collect statistics** before checking that info in TOAD? Do that and see whether the result gets any better.